# SVG Circle radius with CSS

Tags: css, svg, geometry, csslint

I tried to change the radius of SVG Circle with css, and it works in all major browser versions.

The question is why CSS lint complaining about `r` property while all browsers support this just fine!?

Comment: As far as I know only Chrome supports this. Does Chrome count as all major browsers these days?

Comment: Chrome & Safari support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to modify geometric properties, such as `r`, with CSS, is a feature of the upcoming SVG 2 specification.  SVG 2 is not yet a full recommendation, and so far only Chrome (and it sounds like Safari) have implemented this.

I imagine once SVG 2 is a full recommendation, CSS Lint will be updated.

Comment: Nice, cannot wait. Thanks for answer.